# Symfony 3 Form EntityType doesn't prefill from object

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, query-builder

My Choices aka EntityType:class doesn't prefill the select-options.

i have a "contract"-Entity which have values:

```
object(TradePortalBundle\Entity\Contract)[1206]
 private 'id' => int 26
 private 'classification' => int 25
```

where classification (last) should by my default value for selected choice.
my form looks like:

```
$builder
        // Klassifizierung
        ->add('classification', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => 'TradePortalBundle:Dropdowns',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $entityRepository){
                return $entityRepository->createQueryBuilder('d')
                     // select only the right section
                    ->where('d.dropdown_id = 1');
            },
            'choice_label' => 'label',
            'choice_translation_domain' => 'messages',
            'label' => 'contract.form.label.classification'
        ])
};

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefault('data_class', 'TradePortalBundle\Entity\Contract');
}
```

and in my controller i initialize the contract-entity:

```
 /* @var $user User */
 $user = $this->getUser();
 $contract = !$user->getContract() ? new Contract() : $user->getContract();
 $form = $this->createForm(ContractType::class, $contract);
 $form->handleRequest($request);

 if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

 #var_dump($contract);die;

 $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($contract);
 $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush($contract);
}
```

when i persist the contract-entity, everything is allright, the values was saved in the entity. but wy it doesn't prefill the choices?
i expect that the choice with id 25 is prefilled, but the first choice is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because your `TradePortalBundle\Entity\Contract` must hold not id in `classification` field, but an entity

```
object(TradePortalBundle\Entity\Contract)[1206]
 private 'id' => int 26
 private 'classification' => object(TradePortalBundle\Entity\Classification [XXX]
     private 'id' => int 25
```

Comment: that was my first thought too, i try it now with a relation between contract and dropdowns.